# Connection LocalDb to ASP.NET Core and find data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I connected a database, defined connection strings, and I don't quite understand where to see the data itself in localDB. Could you please tell me who knows how to do this?

File `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SportsStore.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var connectionstring = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SportsStoreConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreDbContext>(opts => {
    
    opts.UseSqlServer(connectionstring);
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IStoreRepository, EFStoreRepository>();
 
    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    SeedData.EnsurePopulated(app);
    app.Run();
```

File `StoreDbContext.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SportsStore.Models
{
    public class StoreDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<StoreDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
    }
}
```

File `Product.cs`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SportsStore.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public long? ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

I opened localDB, but I can't find a `Product` data collection

Comment: Well, have you created an EF Core **migration**, and executed it against the local DB to create the database with all its DB objects (like tables etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

There is two approaches to use entity framework

DB first: means usually from the database everything is created and you use `scaffold` command to let EF create entities

code first: which means you create enities and use `Add-Migration 'some name you give to changes'` then followed by  `Update-Database` command to apply your changes

note that for both you need the EF tools package installed

and i highly recommend you to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs)

Comment: yes sorry my bad i have updated the link